# Installing SoapUI on Amazon AMI Linux command line

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, soapui

I need to install and run SoapUI on linux OS (Amazon AMI linux).
This is a command line version (no GUI)

I was able to successfully download and unzip SoapUI tar using the below commands

1. Download SoapUI installation files

   > wget http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/soapui/soapui/5.0.0/SoapUI-5.0.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
2. Extract Contents

   > tar -xzf SoapUI-5.0.0-linux-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
3. Install SoapUI

   > cd /opt/SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/

After this when i run the following command:

> ./soapui.sh

I get below exception

```
java.awt.HeadlessException:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)

at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)

at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)

at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)

at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.startSoapUI(SoapUI.java:842)

at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI$SoapUIRunner.run(SoapUI.java:697)

at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)

at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.r...(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Is there something missing here or any other commands needs to be called ?

Comment: you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689742/8094897

Answer (score 2):

SoapUI itself is a graphical tool, and the main application isn't going to like running without a graphics display.

When I've run the SoapUI stuff on a Linux server without X11, it's been the mock service facility that I'm after - I use it to provide substitute SOAP or REST services for automated testing etc.

The mock service runner runs well without an X11 server - you just have to tell **java** not to look for a graphical user interface.

So you add `-Djava.awt.headless=true`   to the command line:

```
./mockservicerunner.sh -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

If you just to that it will give you a 'help' output, because this tool is designed to use an existing SoapUI project file to provide preconfigured responses, rather than for interactive use.

The alternative is to use X-Forwarding, so SoapUI runs on your server, but the UI is displayed on your local workstation.  I've never done that (because, as I said, I'm after the standalone interaction for automated testing), but this page has some detail:  http://blog.ashwani.co.in/blog/2013-01-10/soapui-mockservicerunner-on-linux-without-x-config/
(it also mentions the 'headless' option for mockservicerunner.sh.

This page has some detail about setting up a project in SoapUI first before using it for one of the automated tools (loadrunner in this case): http://www.soapui.org/load-testing/command-line-execution.html

Comment: i get this exception:

    `2015-09-16 06:57:09,820 [main] WARN  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI -     Could not find jfxrt.jar. Internal browser will be disabled.
    2015-09-16 06:57:09,846 [main] WARN      com.eviware.soapui.analytics.AnalyticsManager - Error generating     Analytics session ID - returning empty String
    java.net.UnknownHostException: qadev-ops-automation-c: qadev-ops-    automation-c: Name or service not known
            at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1496)`

Answer (score 2):

I just installed and executed SoapUI in AWS (Red Hat) without using any graphical interface:

1.- Download SoapUI directly from soapui.org; search for the latest Linux version, copy the link address and download the software into any Linux directory using the wget command. This should have downloaded an installation script file (for example, SoapUI-x64--5.3.0.sh).

2.- Execute the previous installation script from command line and answer the installation prompts. Once you have finished go to the directory where you elected to install it and verify that you have all the folders and files (bin, lib, etc.).

3.- To run SoapUI from the command prompt, go to your SoapUI home directory and  execute an instruction like this:

```
sh  bin/testrunner.sh -s"Your Suite Name" -c"Your Test Case Name" -f/your/output/path/ /your/project/path/your-soapui-project.xml
```