# How to do Command line installation of SoapUI Open Source on Linux server?

Tags: soapui

I am installing SoapUI Open Source on my Linux server.

For installtion I am executing following commands:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
cd /opt/SoapUI-5.4.0/bin/
./soapui.sh
```

While installtion last step (./soapui.sh) is giving me following error:

```
05:11:16,498 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
```

When I use 'export DISPLAY=:0.0' , step ./soapui.sh goes in long run and need to abort manually with following message -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
```

Kindly suggest solution for Command line installation of SoapUI Open Source on Linux.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't provide a solution to your question, but SoapUI is an GUI program. There is no CLI installation.

Comment: What do you expect when you run `./soapui.sh` on a Linux terminal?

Comment: @Rao Running `./soapui.sh` should install the SoapUI in Linux.

Comment: @kishs1991, since you are using `tar` ball installer, installation is complete with command `tar -xzf SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to run soapui.sh script for installtion as SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz aready has the testrunner.sh. Thanks to @Rao .

You can execute it as below:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
/opt/SoapUI-5.4.0/bin/testrunner.sh -r soapui-project.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

Download .sh file from soapui.org
  Go to downloaded folder
Give the execution permission to .sh file 
  chmod +x ./SoapUI*.sh
Then,
  sudo ./SoapUI*.sh
Installer window open tnen follow step and click on next.